# Enable fade to black/grey when in fullscreen

Tags: windows-7, vlc-media-player

I wish to blackout or grayout my other monitor when using VLC in fullscreen.

I've searched around and there seems to be an option for it, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i'm aware, the option is only available in OSX. There is certainly no option in my version (latest) and i am running 3 monitors.

Comment: That's unfortunate. Do you of any other way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I recently found [XBMC](http://xbmc.org/) which has this feature. But that's a media center.